# How mysql compare LONG strings internal

Tags: mysql

I have to compare post contents in mysql to avoid repost the same content

`...WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM posts p
  WHERE  p.content = stg.content);`

I wanner to know how mysql compare two string internal, did they scan the string one character by character?

And Will this lead to some performance issue if I am about do a lot compare at a time?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not compare post contents at mysql side, for example , if you use php, you can compute the md5 value of post contents, and save it this record into mysql, next time , if you want insert post contents into mysql, compute the md5 value and check whether it's already save into mysql.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but how mysql compare the value in text fields. I wonder if they are also comparing the MD5 value.